# Изменить индексы в массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив $my_array:

```
Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (            [image] => 0.jpg        )
        [6] => Array
            (            [image] => 1.jpg        )
        [8] => Array
            (            [image] => 2.jpg        )
    )
```

Как изменить индексы, чтоб начинались с нуля и дальше по порядку? Вот так:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (            [image] => 0.jpg        )
        [1] => Array
            (            [image] => 1.jpg        )
        [2] => Array
            (            [image] => 2.jpg        )
    )
```

Я упростил подмассивы, для простоты отображения.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Функция [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-values.php) заново индексирует возвращаемый массив числовыми индексами:

```
array_values($my_array);
```

Comment: Вот так заработало! $my_array = array_values($my_array); Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php



$data=array('3' => array('image0' => '0.jpg'),
      '6' => array('image1' => '1.jpg'),
      '8' => array('image2' => '2.jpg'));

print_r(array_values($data));
// другой вариант
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        # code...
$data1[]=$value;

    }


print_r($data1);



?>
```